# Docker: Map external to internal user (howto apply '--user', howte execute .bashrc)?

Tags: docker, docker-volume, linux-namespaces

Running a docker image with a command line such as:

```
> docker run -it -v $OutsideDir:$InsideDir -u $(id -u):$(id -g) c0ffeebaba bash
```

I am able to work on my data as the current user on the host from inside the docker container. However, asking inside the container 'whoami' gives the response that the UID is unknown.

So the shell is executed on a user without a home-directory. How
can I get some initialization being done for that user? Is there a way to map the user id and group id of an external user to a specific user name from inside? Can this be done dynamically, so that it would work for any user, specified through the '--user' flag as shown above?

My first approach would have been to use 'CMD' in the Dockerfile such as

```
CMD ["source", "/home/the_user/.bashrc" ]
```

But, that does not work.

Comment: If they're local users, mount `/etc/passwd` to `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` to `/etc/group` and the home directory. To get it to 'full user' run `bash --login`

Comment: That is an interesting option. However, that makes it host/user dependent.

Comment: how so? a wrapper around `docker run` that abstracts most of these complications by generating an `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` file, as well as mounting the home directory by default would get you a long way towards your goal.

Comment: I would tag your answer as the solution ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A relatively simple solution would be to wrap the docker run in a script, mapping in the `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` files from the host onto the container, as well as the user's home directory, so something like:

```
#!/bin/bash -p

# command starts with mapping passwd and group files
cmd=(docker run -v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro -v /etc/group:/etc/group:ro)
# add home directory:
myhome=$(getent passwd $(id -nu) | awk -F: '{print $6}')
cmd+=(-v $myhome:$myhome)
# add userid and groupid mappings:
cmd+=(-u $(id -u):$(id -g))

# then pass through any other arguments:
cmd+=("$@")

"${cmd[@]}"
```

This can be run as:

```
./runit.sh -it --rm alpine id
```

or, for a shell (alpine doesn't have bash by default):

```
./runit.sh -it --rm centos bash --login
```

You can throw in a `-w $HOME` to get it to start in the user's home directory, etc.

Comment: Mapping the auth files works great when the host is Ubuntu, but not at all when the host is Centos. That is true regardless of container O/S. I'm still struggling to figure out why. `ls -l /etc | grep passwd` prints a bunch of question marks.

Comment: It is also useful to map /etc/shadow:/etc/shadow:ro so that you can use `sudo` inside the container.

Comment: sounds like you don't have execute access on `/etc`, which is causing the issue on CentOS. Generally I don't map the shadow file because I'm not planning on elevating things running in the container - I use this procedure to run build scripts with my own userid, thus avoiding complications regarding things ending up owned as root in my home directory. I've evolved this procedure quite a bit to work on systems without entries in /etc, but it was done at work, so I can't share it directly.